# How to count an object's citation number?

Tags: c++

Assume an object can be cited (or referenced) by other objects. Currently I use a member variable to record its citation count. The citation count is used to determine if the object can be deleted or not.

```
class Cited
{
public:
    int m_citationCount;
};
```

I make the variable public. When the object is cited, it is increased by 1. If it is uncited, it is decreased by 1. Making the variable public doesn't seem proper. If it has only one type of citer, I can make the citer type a friend. However, there may be all kinds of citers. Any better idea to do it?

More information: These objects are items or nodes in a tree structure. Some nodes may reference other nodes. For example, a node is called air which represents material air with its properties like density. A node called background may reference the air node to show the background is air. Operations on the tree are undoable. If a user deletes the background node, it is just pushed in an undo stack. It is not really deleted.

Comment: By "citation", what do you mean? Is this some kind of academic resource indexing system or something like that? Or are you talking about ordinary reference-counting? You may want to look at [shared pointers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106508/what-is-a-smart-pointer-and-when-should-i-use-one).

Comment: It's a bad idea to expose `m_citationCount` as a public variable. At the least, control it with public functions -- `incrementCitationCount()` and `decrementCitationCount()` come to mind.

Comment: Better names would be `cite` and `uncite`.

Comment: Have a look at [persistent tree data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure#Trees).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could potentially work out a scheme using a shared_ptr with a custom deleter that would do whatever you need it to when the count drops to zero.

Or you could roll something manually. At a minimum it would probably be a good idea to make the count variable private and provided public methods to do the work:

```
class Cited
{
public:
    void CreateCitation()
    {
        ++m_citationCount;
    }

    void RemoveCitation()
    {
        --m_citationCount;

        if(m_citationCount == 0)
        {
            // ... whatever special logic happens at zero.
        }
    }

private:
    int m_citationCount;
};
```

But that could be taken further by creating a Citation class to act rather like a smart pointer. Such a class would be returned by CreateCitation, would keep a pointer to the Cited object, and would call RemoveCitation in its destructor.

For example:

```
class Citation
{
public:
    Citation(Cited* c) : m_cited(c) {}

    ~Citation()
    {
        m_cited->RemoveCitation();
    }

    // ... whatever else to make this more usable.

    Cited* m_cited;
};
```

Those are just the basic ideas. There's various aspects that would need to be polished up (such as dealing with the Citation class's copy constructor and assignment operator).

Answer (score 3):

Save yourself the grief and just use C++'s [`shared_ptr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/) template.

---

OK, now that the question has been changed, the answer needs to as well.

Basically, you just need to employ a few strategies:

## Linking using `shared_ptr`

Any time you need to keep track of a node, use a `shared_ptr<Node>` where `Node` is your node class. For example, if a `Node` needs to refer to another `Node`, then it **has a** `shared_ptr<Node>` to do so. For exampleworking off your example, you could have:

class Material: public Node {
    // Material properties here
};

class Background: public Node {
    // Material properties here
    void SetMaterial(shared_ptr mat);
};

void set_stage() {
    shared_ptr air = new Material(/*constructor parameters*/);
    shared_ptr skyBG = new Background(/*constructor parameters*/);
    skyBG->SetMaterial(air);
}

## Undo support

To have undo support, remember that an undo stack is generally a stack of actions, and each action contains enough information to figure out what was done (so it can be undone). If an action involves a node, then it should (like everything else) use a `shared_ptr<Node>` to refer to it.

Comment: Those cited objects and citers are in fact undoable which are not really deleted. Thus, shared_ptr may not be used.

Comment: @user1899020 with the addition of this comment, I'm having a _really hard_ time understanding the problem you're solving.  What is "in fact undoable"?  It now sounds like you're adding `weak_ptr` to the problem.

Comment: @DrewDormann These objects are items or nodes in a tree structure. Some nodes may reference other nodes. For example, a node is called air which represents material air with its properties like density. A node called background may reference the air node to show the background is air. Operations on the tree are undoable. If a user deletes the background node, it is just pushed in an undo stack. It is not really deleted.

Comment: @user1899020: I'm not sure what you're trying to convey, but you may be interested to know that `shared_ptr` allows you to specify a custom deleter. That might solve some of your problems.

Comment: @user1899020: Ok, then stick a `shared_ptr` in the undo stack, which will keep it alive.